# Changed the date format - still getting incorrect date value

Tags: php, mysql

I have gone through the list of questions. I have changed the date format which is acceptable for mysql. But still I'am facing error.

This is my input type for the date.

```
 Expected Completion Date <input type="date" id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="t_date"/>
```

This is the way am getting the value.

```
$date = $_POST['t_date'];
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
$sql = "insert into task (task_name,manager_name,project_name,complete_date) values ('$tname',$mid,$pid,$newDate)";
```

This is the error which I'am facing.

> Error: insert into task (task_name,manager_name,project_name,complete_date) values ('server part',2,5,2014-11-17)
>   Incorrect date value: '1986' for column 'complete_date' at row 1

Please help if i did any mistake.

Comment: Wrap your date value in quotes (`'`) in your `insert` statement; otherwise you have the result of a subtraction (2014 - 11 - 26 = 1977)

Comment: But you really should be learning about prepared statements and bind variables for your SQL

Comment: Mysql database have default date format as 'Y-m-d H:i:s' . So create your date in that format and insert. 
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));

Comment: @Mark Baker I was not aware about prepared statements. But I will learn that.